# C# Split Byte Array Until Errors

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm splitting a longString into a byteArray based on set sizes. However, sometimes there is extra data included and I then need it to stop at the last size that fitted. How would I be able to do that?

The code used is below to call the method.

```
  List<byte[]> playerssp = splitDataToByteArray(bplayers, 1348);
```

The function that does the split.

```
    private static List<byte[]> splitDataToByteArray(byte[] longString, int size)
    {
        byte[] source = longString;
        //MessageBox.Show(source.Length.ToString());
        List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i += size)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(source, i, buffer, 0, size);
            result.Add(buffer);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Run your loop to `i < (source.Length/size)*size` instead? If length is 101, and size is 10, then flooring the length to 100 with an int divide means that the last loop that runs is i==90 and you don't get an attempt to copy bytes 100 to 110..

Comment: You can also set the loop invariant to `i + size <= source.Length`. Since each split contains the range ```[i,i+size)```, the upper bound just needs to be within source.Length.

Comment: Use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) `return longString.Chunk(size).Where( x => x.Length == size).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.Net 6`, then you can use `Enumerable.Chunk`. You just have to check whether the last element is of the correct size or not.

```
private static List<byte[]> splitDataToByteArray(byte[] longString, int size)
{
    var result = longString.Chunk(size).ToList();
    var lastChunck = result[result.Count - 1];

    if(lastChunck.Length != size)
    {
        result.Remove(lastChunck);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly thank you very much!